# Why does assert last_response.body.include?('[String]') give a false positive?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rack

When doing unit testing in Sinatra using `Rack` and `Test::Unit`, `last_response.body.include?` gave me a false positive using a non-present test string.

Why does `assert last_response.body.include?('string')` give a false positive when `'string'` isn't in the response body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check before if page was loaded correctly using:

```
assert last_response.ok?
```